# Applying regex-based filter in basic sparql query returns no results

Tags: sparql, opendata

The following query:

```
PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject
WHERE 
{
  ?x qb:component ?subject .
}
```

deployed via this publicly available endpoint: http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql-beta produces a list of available subjects:

```
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/component-specification/pupil-attainment/refArea
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/component-specification/pupil-attainment/refPeriod
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/component-specification/pupil-attainment/measureType
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/component-specification/pupil-attainment/count
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/component-specification/pupil-attainment/pupils
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/component-specification/pupil-attainment/ratio
```

## Problem

I would like to filter the available results using regex, similary to the [linked example](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_filters.html):

```
PREFIX vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#>

SELECT ?g
WHERE
{ ?y vcard:Given ?g .
  FILTER regex(?g, "r", "i") }
```

when attempted:

```
PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject
WHERE 
{
  ?a qb:component ?subject .
  FILTER regex(?subject, "p", "i")
}
```

the query returns table with no rows. Is there a way I could filter the obtained values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should call the `str` function on `?subject`, it is not a string but rather a URI, so first you have to convert it to a string.

This should work:

```
PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject
WHERE 
{
  ?a qb:component ?subject .
  FILTER regex(str(?subject), "p", "i")
}
```